# Can we receive gmail push notifications for multiple users by creating different subscriptions to same topic using cloud pub/sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail, gmail-api, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am developing an application where users register their Gmail accounts. I want to receive
new mail notifications for all the users who are registered with my application.
I have followed below steps -
1. Created a Google console project and a topic for my application.
2. Authorized google service account to publish new mail notifications to my topic.
3. Added signed in user to the Iampolicy so that then can subscribe to my topic.
4. Created a watch request for each signed in user by specifying the webhook url.

With the above steps I am able to receive the new mail notifications for one user but when I try to follow 
the same steps for different users I am not receiving anything on the web hook url.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At StackOverflow, we are helping developers to get stronger. However, we won't never let company get rid of them by requesting free jobs on this forum. So in order to distinct yourself from these sharks, show us some effort, pieces of code, some bugs, or other... And then we will help you! Please take the tour and read "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" [help/dont-ask], "What topics can I ask about here?" [help/on-topic] and [mcve]!